# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

Last night my host experienced what they call **"InnoDB engine server is broken"**.  It took awhile but they did a recovery but had some issues with missing tables.  I also found out that we didn't have any backups.  I had switched from cloud to dedicated and found out (after the fact) that the auto backup wasn't included and that I had to order separately.

I do have a problem with a missing table on http://bit.ly/1STElBF

I looked up some solutions, but I'm not sure if they apply to me.  My host seems to think they don't but I was hoping someone could help me with this?

The error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>       'firstgea_shop.core_store' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* 
>   FROM `core_store` AS `main_table` ORDER BY CASE WHEN main_table.store_id = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, main_table.sort_order ASC, main_table.name ASC

Trace:

```
#0 /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/firstgea/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(736): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/firstgea/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/firstgea/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Store/Collection.php(174): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load(false, false)
#10 /home/firstgea/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(752): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Store_Collection->load()
#11 /home/firstgea/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(635): Varien_Data_Collection->count()
#12 /home/firstgea/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(477): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#13 /home/firstgea/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#14 /home/firstgea/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/firstgea/public_html/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all - create backup  of all database that you have right now.**

Looks like you haven't basic table. Without this table Magento can't work at all.

If you have other tables, only this one missing - you can try to install Magento to OTHER database and copy this table with [mysqldump & mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables) .

If websites data is not important for you (as example if it's new website, or test website) - you can just re-install Magento.

Anyway, best of all - to perform any actions only by Magento developer.

Comment: thank you.  I went ahead and had backups made of the site.  Since i don't sell anything on this site, I don't care about customer data.  i just worried about products and design.  Will that make a difference if i reinstalled Magento?

Comment: Your theme is not located in DB, so you can migrate it to another magento installation.
But categories, products - are inside DB.
If you have missing only one or few tables - you can try use copy of "newly installed magento". If you haven't any tables - no metter, unfortuanally you can't restore them. Only if you can find any backups (maybe some old one).

Comment: Is there a simple way I can copy products from the site?   I contacted a support company and they said it would take over 40 hrs

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: actually your core_store table doesn't exist,  copy this table and import  to your db firstgea_shop and problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

- First of all create a backup for your files and database (important)
- Second try to create new empty database, then go through magento wizard to let magento build its tables in this new database.
- After that  try to restore the original database to the new database created by magento.
  In this case magento will replace the new tables with the original tables, and of course will keep the tables that is not exist in the original. it worked for me in the past